# Do I need to apply for the UK transit visa?

Tags: uk, transit, indian-citizens, lhr, h1b-visas

I am traveling to India from United States and transiting through Heathrow Airport, London. My H-1B got approved this year but passport is not stamped yet. As of now, passport includes a visa stamp for F-1 visa.

Will I need to apply for the UK transit visa given that my F1 is not in effect anymore and I don't have stamping for H-1B?

I answered the questions on the following link to understand whether of not I need a transit visa- https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa. It says you are exempt for the transit visa if you hold a visa for United States. But I am not entirely sure if my situation qualify for this exemption.

Thank you in advance.

PS:

1. I have 3 hours of layover (in the same calendar day) at the Heathrow airport
2. Nationality: Indian

Comment: LHR airport has transit area so you will not need to actually enter UK during transit. So you don't need a visa.

Comment: @dimnnv Thank you for your reply. Their official website says that one may still need 'AirSide Transit Visa' if they aren't going through border control - https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/direct-airside-transit-visa

Comment: @dimnnv, in some cases people need a transit visa even when there is a transit area.

Comment: I think you need a transit visa. Having H-1B approval is not the same as having a valid visa stamp in your passport.

Comment: By F1 not in effect, do you mean that your status has ended according to the U.S. law (e.g. your studies have ended) or that the visa stamp has expired in your passport according to the validity stated in the foil?

Comment: @dimnnv there are many countries, including the UK and Schengen countries, where connecting passengers from certain countries need a transit visa even if they stay airside (in the “secure” or “international” area) and do not enter the country or go through passport control. Look up Airport Transit Visa (Schengen) or Direct Airside Transit Visa (UK) for instance.

Comment: @jcaron Ok I see. Thanks for clarification.